# Why can I no longer use the PS3 web browser on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

Until recently, I was able to log into Stack Overflow using the webbrowser (Mobile IE) on my PS3.  The latest PS3 update appears to have added better session support to the browser, so I don't know exactly when Stack Overflow stopped allowing me to login.

Currently, if I go to the login page I see: "or provide the openid:" - there's no images & links to forward to my provider for sync'ing authentication.

I had noticed a few weeks ago that functionality had been severely limited - no voting (up, down, on comments, or to close).  All I could do was edit the question and add/edit answers.  But adding answers was now prompting me with a captcha, though I was logged in :/

It was a pain that I'd get a 404 on successfully adding an answer, though refreshing would work just fine.  The captcha addition didn't change anything with this regard...

Comment: Mobile IE? I have never wanted a PS3 less...

Comment: I can only imagine the dedication that would lead one to browse SO on one's PS3.

Comment: Either that, or you're taking the whole SO-as-game theory far too seriously.

Comment: Um, where did you get your information that the PS3 uses IE?

Comment: Sony PS3 has it's own web browser unless you are using some sort of modded firmware.

Comment: When I browse the internet on my PS3, I get messages saying "your version of IE is not supported..." for various embedded videos.  Whatever it is, browsing SO on it doesn't work like it used to.

Comment: If all you want to do is *look* at the site, try [this](http://stackmobile.com).

Answer (score 7):

Hmm. I was curious what web browser the PS3 does use, and apparently, it's crazy:

> The PlayStation 3 uses a version of the [NetFront browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetFront) by Access Co. as its internal web browser. It is the same browser used in the PSP (Sony-branded NetFront 2.81) with the same interface, menus and virtual keyboard. Its user agent string is cloaked, falsely reporting as Mozilla/5.0 (PLAYSTATION 3; 1.00).

That was in 2006, though, so I don't know how much has changed. Can't find much else on any updates.

Based on this thread title of ["Will Sony -ever- update the PS3 web browser?"](http://boardsus.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-Updates/Will-Sony-ever-update-the-PS3-web-browser/td-p/46021152/page/4) and dated 8-14-2010, perhaps not much *has* changed..

Looks like the PS3 is rolling out another browser update with 4.10 firmware (Feb/Mar 2012?) and it might stop sucking.. possibly:

http://www.shacknews.com/article/72361/ps3-firmware-410-improves-internet-browser

Comment: Yeah. The PS3's browser is incredibly horrible.

Comment: If anyone cares (!), as an FYI the debugging firmware allows you to switch to WebKit, and this can be easily enabled with a custom firmware.  I don't really use my PS3 browser enough to warrant hacking the firmware for this, but I guess some people might.

Comment: I can see you're busy on important things in your waning weeks :)

Comment: @adam it's an interesting bit of trivia to me, no idea why