# JLU SE site doesn't work in PS3 browser

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange-2.0, browsers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

I try to vote, post comments, view vote counts, post answers, but to no avail--the buttons simply don't do anything when I click on them. When using the PS3 browser I can't do anything useful on the Japanese language and usage stackexchange site, other than read posts. Oddly enough though, this is only the case on the JLU site. I figured that it may have been because it was a beta site, but that doesn't seem to be the case because the DSP beta works just fine for me. Any assistance on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a PlayStation?

Comment: My first reaction was to tell you that [the PS3 browser is unsupported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need?lq=1), but it looks like [there's a small chance that that might have changed a few months ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62185/131713).

Comment: @random yes, PlayStation 3

Comment: @PopularDemand yea I suspected that too. But unsupported for just one site?

Comment: Unsupported means: may or may not work, may break without warning, may look like crap - we don't intentionally *break it*, but we do no testing on it and make no effort to ensure that it works either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't really support this browser.

Chances are, *something* is breaking the loading of JavaScript on that site - the Japanese site has [a bit of extra script](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199/jlu-hacks-ruby-rendering) to make the text work properly, so that's probably where the blame lies. Heck, it's possible the PS3 browser can't handle Japanese characters in some fashion.

Comment: "Heck, it's possible the PS3 browser can't handle Japanese characters in some fashion." That would be ironic.

Comment: Indeed it would. But, it does actually display the Japanese characters and even the ruby text perfectly.